# VBA for MS Word not looping through all sentences in a paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word, text-segmentation

I am trying to loop through all the sentences in a Word document and parse them into semi-HTML code.  During testing, I ran into an interesting situation where any sentence followed by a non-closed sentence would be skipped.  For example, if I have the following two sentences:

> This is the first sentence in a paragraph with special characters and
>   there should be one more sentence.  This is the second sentence that
>   should be there.**

When I loop through each sentence in the paragraph.range.sentences, I only get the first sentence and the ".**" at the end of the paragraph.  However, if I add a space between the period and the astriks, then the code works ". **".

How can I make sure the macro reads all the text in a sentence, even if there isn't a space after the period?  My example code is below:

```
Public Sub ParseDoc()
Dim paras As Paragraphs
Dim para As Paragraph
Dim sents As Sentences
Dim sent As Range


    Set paras = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    For Each para In paras
        Set sents = para.Range.Sentences
        For Each sent In sents
            MsgBox (sent.Text)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to "read" all the characters in the sentence in the format of "words.special_character", but I realized that if I replaced all period+special_character instances in the Word document, all my For Each loops work.  I used the following code at the very beginning of my sub module and everything worked as expected:

```
'Adds a <SPACE> between a period and a non-alphanumeric character
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    .Text = ".([!0-9A-z ])"
    .Replacement.Text = ". \1"
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem with the first asterisk. changing that first asterisk to anything else and this code runs as you are hoping. I do not know if this is a special behavior, but if you reference `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Sentences(2).text` the full text of the sentence is as you are expecting.

A simple reworking of the loop(s) using while...wend and incremental counters, you can reference the items using their index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I noticed something similar with a "#" character, but most text characters are OK.  It's a little curious why this is happening.  Let me rewrite my loops and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I did look very quickly for any notes about escape sequences but there're a lot of irrelevant search results.